# three js highlight box while using fly controls

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to have a object highlighted while using fly controls? Like [this](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lensflares) but the boxes highlighting when you click them. What I ultimately want it to do is to click on a object and then it go onto a website. But for the moment I have tried to just highlight a object when it its clicked using:

```
        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( mesh );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );


            }

            /*
            // Parse all the faces
            for ( var i in intersects ) {

                intersects[ i ].face.material[ 0 ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff | 0x80000000 );

            }
            */
```

But this does not seem to work when I'm using fly controls is it possible? If not could the object just be highlighted to show some text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this with the fly controls, its working fine. Make sure to raycast against an **array that contains your meshes** or just `scene.children` in this case.

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1; 

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );   

    // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

    }

}
container.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```

Three.js r.71

Consider checking out https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents to easily add DOM Events like `click` or `mouseover` to your meshes.